# Automating Printing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large number of links I want to print. The links are in local HTML files, so I am able to add scripts to them. I attempted a few things, but I did not get to the end. The best I have so-far achieved is to open the links I want to print in separate tabs, and the Windows.print() function does not work. Could someone help me to what I might be missing here, or point me to how I might get to my goal. Please see the code below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Print</title>
   <script>
      function pickLinks() {
         const anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
         for (const a of anchors) {
            const url = a.href;
            const urlBase = "https://www.huffpost.com/entry/";
            if (url.startsWith(urlBase)) {
               console.log(getQid(url));
               openInNewTab(url);
            }
         }
      }

      function getQid(url) {
         const res = url.split("-");
         return res[res.length - 1];
      }

      function openInNewTab(url) {
         const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
         win.print();
         //win.focus();
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Print</h1>
   <button onclick="pickLinks()">PRINT</button>
   <a href="https://www.huffpost.com/entry/coronavirus-face-masks-everything-you-need-to-know_l_5e8ca647c5b6e1a2e0faa947">Link</a>
   <a href="https://www.huffpost.com/entry/best-coronavirus-face-mask-materials-new-study_l_5e99b576c5b6a92100e63129">Link</a>
   <a href="https://time.com/">Link</a>
   <a href="https://www.huffpost.com/entry/is-it-safe-people-use-bathroom-coronavirus_l_5ef43b8fc5b66c3126820ec8">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would like the print to be a PDF with a filename that reflects the URL, such as getQid(url) in the code above.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: using the ```print()``` method will only pop up the print dialog in whichever browser you are using, this will not automatically print the page you go to.  I don't believe you would be able to automatically print the page that you navigate to simply because this is a browser function and cannot be manipulated from the DOM.  You might want to look at something like ```Puppeteer``` to possibly do this, but other than that I'm not sure that it is entirely possible to automate such a function.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. However, the print() function does not even pop up the dialog to print. At the moment, I have to print every link manually, so anything that helps to shave off some of the manual effort is useful. Puppeteer did look interesting and lead me to headless Chrome which might help me. In particular, this: "chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf https://www.chromestatus.com/" looks promising. I will explore this. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Ok I see what you're saying now, not exactly sure why that wouldn't pop up the print dialog.  Yes puppeteer is good if you're trying to automate things within specific browsers.